# Creating an Excel 2010 formula to size mailbox limits?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I would like to create an Excel formula that will look at the value in column "G" and then round off the value to an increment of 5000mb as long as there is 2000mb free.

If value in G is 15008, the rounded off value in Column E should be 20000.
If value in G is 12959, the rounded off value in Column E should be 15000.

If value in G is 9893, the rounded off value should be 15000 because we don't want to go to 10000 as this would be less than the 2000mb required, rounding off to 15000.

I hope this makes sense and someone out there is able to come up with a formula for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your value is in `G1`, `=(ROUNDDOWN((G1+2000)/5000,0)+1)*5000` should work

This takes the value in `G1` and adds your 2000 mb buffer in order to determine how many 5000 mb "blocks" this space would require. The formula then rounds that number down to a whole number of "blocks" (which is then too small for the current value + buffer) and then adds an additional "block" to allow enough space for the current value + buffer. Then multiplying by 5000 gives you the total number of mb.

[image]